# remove validation on name in laravel 6 on creating new user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I want to remove validation on the name in laravel 6 on creating a new user. The user is created successfully but when I enter a name with space or capital letters, the login page opens up. But if I remove all spaces from the name everything works fine with the following code.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'    => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $username = slugify($data['name']) . "-" . mt_rand(10000, 99999);

    return User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'username' => $username,
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

blade.php code

https://codeshare.io/5e1kX7

Comment: When you say "the login page opens up" is this happening instead of saving the user to the database, or are you having trouble with logging a user in if you've included a space in the name?

Comment: it happens only when i am putting space in name

Comment: I realise from your question that "something" happens when you put a space in the name but my comment was asking what specifically happens. Please can you explain in more detail what you expect should happen that isn't happening or what isn't happening that should be happening.

Comment: I wants to sucessfully register even when i put space or not...

Comment: So, a user isn't added to the database when you add a space in the name?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//...
'name' => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/', 'max:255'],
//...
```

Comment: No i don't get any error but i moved to login page and values saved to database

Comment: Yes, if validation fail you must get an error validation message

Comment: But if validation failed why values stored to database...?

Comment: I can't see any validation call inside create method ?!

Comment: Could you plz add the full code of your controller and blade file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207892/discussion-between-foued-moussi-and-upasana-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding regex in the validation

```
'name' => ['required', 'string','regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u', 'max:255'],
```